# Add text to empty label in div without adding height to div

Tags: html, height

the problem is the following in have some inputs between css line separators, they are all alined vertically, and have labels beneath the inputs.

the problem is when there is a validation error , some text is put inside this labels, making them visible, this makes the div bigger and causes the container div to have bigger height therefore input is no longer aligned vertically.

is there a way so the label can already have height diferent from zero when there is no text?

Comment: style={height:"auto"} ?

Comment: the inline style definition for the div

Comment: <div id="someId" style={height:"auto"}></div>

Comment: i dont understand , how will these not affect the height of the div when a label is added?

Answer (score 4):

Does this help?
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/BKrHq/

**Approach 1**
in this solution, div containing label is given a fixed height according to font size.

**html**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txt" value="label content"/>
</div>
<div id="labDiv">
    <label id="lab"></label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Show Content in label" id="showLab" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
#labDiv{
    height:18px;  
}
```

**Approach 2** in this approach, label is given text : a space character - `&nbsp;` to get it to the actual height , same as when it will contain the text.

js fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/4Bazb/

**html**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txt" value="label content" />
</div>
<div>
    <label id="lab">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Show Content in label" id="showLab" />
</div>
```

quick implementation of **approach 2** :

if you have a common class for all such labels then you can use `:before` in css to add a space quickly.

if the class is : errorLabels

```
.errorLabels::before
{
content:"\00a0";
}
```

Comment: I am trying out the first approch i will let you know.. thank you

Comment: i think approach 2 is more suitable and quick.

Comment: i've just updated the answer to add a quicker approach

Answer (score 0):

Just set a min-height for label div in css. It means that even if there is no tag the label is going to have some height but if text increases then label will adapt to the height of the text inside it.

```
#labelDiv{
min-height:14px;  
}
```